# Is there a way to save an auto variable and use it afterwards?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I am trying to save a block of code and to use it afterwards.So I shall be able to declare the auto variable as global, assign it and then invoke the block:

```
// In the header
auto __myblock; // error
```

Then:

```
__myblock=[]()
{
    <code>
};
<other code>
__myblock();
```

But the problem is that I get a syntax error: it seems like I must initialize the variable in the moment I declare it, so I am not able to memorize that block and use it afterwards.I need to memorize the block as a global variable or inside a class.Also inside a class I am not allowed to declare an auto as instance variable.Is there a way?

Comment: Don't use double underscores in your names. Anything with those is reserved for the implementation. Anyway, is it always going to be a lambda with the same function signature? If so, just declare it as the proper `std::function` type.

Comment: `auto` variables must be initialized when created. You can't use it the way you did.

Comment: @chris: That's a good idea, and it would probably suit the OP's needs.  But it should be noted that it's not the same thing, and the `std::function` would have worse performance characteristics than a bare lambda.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, True, I'm typically never worried about performance unless it's mentioned for a good reason. Depending on the code, it could make no real difference at all.

Comment: If your lambda doesn't capture, why don't you just use a regular function?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Presumably, to keep things inline. Even a capturing lambda can be substituted by a functor definition out of line, and that's no reason to do it all the time.

Comment: @LucDanton: By "to keep things inline", do you mean defining it at its point of usage?  What's the point of doing that, in this case?  He's already declaring it outside its point of usage, *and* giving it a name.  I'm not shy about using lambdas, my code has become littered with them over the past 2 years, but I can't see anything useful that a lambda offers here.  And yes, you're right about using a function object class.  If he does need to capture, then that is definitely what he should be using here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions within your question:

1. Can I declare auto variable ahead of time (before initialization)
2. How to I store lambda functions

The answer to the first question is 'no': declaration of auto variables must come with the initialization. You can't have:

```
auto x;  // error
x = 42;
```

by itself, because the compiler wouldn't know at the declaration what x should be. On the other hand:

```
auto x = 42;
```

is valid, because 42 is int, so the compiler allocate an integer for x

For the second question use std::function. It is as optimized as it can be. There are some details to consider. Specifically: is the code block <code> refers to variables outside the scope of the lambda function. If it does, do you want it to reference those variable by value or by reference. All those variables has to be stored somewhere (a.k.a. capture), and this is what std::function does. If you don't have any capture, std::function is basically a simple pointer to function, which is as optimized as it can be. At the header have:

```
// with no capture:
std::function<void()> _myblock;

// if you have capture (say, two integers)
std::function<void(int,int)> _myblock
```

and at the source have:

```
// no capture:
_myblock = []() { <code> }

// with capture:
_myblock = [x,y]( int x, int y) { <code> }
```

Finally, as one of the commenters pointed out, if you don't have a capture, best thing to do is to simply factor out <code> code into a function and simply call it later.

Comment: The capture code is a bit strange here. `[x,y]{ <code> }` doesn't meed to take the integers as parameters, it can access them without that.

Comment: @Xeo, you are correct. No need to have the formal argument (and indeed, the form without the argument is the canonical form) in the lambda. I added it for readability, but definitely can be removed.